# Sumproduct if equals with removing blanks

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

I'm trying to count cells that start with a certain date equal to a cell using sumproduct which works fine unless the array includes blanks.

Through a lot of google searches and stackoverflow searches, i've managed to come up with the below code, i've tried at least 20-25 variants with none giving the intended result, including CSE/array formulas

Evaluating the formula shows that the second array is keeping the blanks and giving a #Value error which i can't remove from the array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((BB3:BB33)<>"",--(DAY(BB3:BB33)=DAY(A38)))
```

A38 is in the format 11/09.
Range BB3:BB33 is dates (with times unsplit due to how data is pulled)

```
11/09/2019 08:14
11/09/2019 08:14
10/09/2019 23:20
10/09/2019 23:20
10/09/2019 23:20
10/09/2019 23:20
10/09/2019 23:20
10/09/2019 23:20
BLANK
BLANK
etc, etc.
```

the output should be 2 for A38 which when the range only includes non-blanks is correct but the blanks override the result to #Value

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Try moving your bracket and adding a math operation `=SUMPRODUCT(--(BB3:BB33<>""),--(DAY(BB3:BB33)=DAY(A38)))` OR add a math operation and get rid of -- by using =SUMPRODUCT((BB3:BB33<>"")*(DAY(BB3:BB33)=DAY(A38)))

Comment: are the blanks actually empty or are they ""?  Is the date time text or and excel serial date being properly displayed as a date and time format?  `ISTEXT(BB3)` is a quick test to see if its text.

Comment: In a helper column break down your individual parts of the SUMPRODUCT and see which cells are causing the problem and potentially which formula is the issue.  ie in BC3 use `=(BB3<>"")` .  In BD3 use `=(DAY(BB3)=DAY($A$38))`.  Copy those formulas down to row 33 and do you get TRUE and FALSE where you expect it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Sorry for the late response, i've been OOTO, I've tried all your suggestions but unfortunately still no luck. The problem appears in the 'DAY(BB3:BB33)=DAY(A38)' part as any blank returns #Value which causes the entire formula to return #Value. it appears trying to compare with sumproduct isn't a valid use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've FINALLY managed to solve this with a much simpler solution (After many many attempts). This ignores the blanks completely which were the cells causing issues for sumproduct.

```
=COUNTIFS(BB3:BB33,">"&DATEVALUE(A38))
```

Doesn't require CSE.